# Trying to get a Java GUI application using Swing and Frame to run as a docker image

Tags: java, docker

I have a Java application that connects to an Amazon EC2 server that I have previously set up that runs a collaborative whiteboard application in the Frame GUI using the swing and awt java libraries and using socket programming on the port: 8888. The application works fine, however I am struggling to get it to work as a docker image. I have exported the project as a .jar file called 'col_whiteboard.jar', and the class within the jar file that I want to run is called 'DrawCanvas'. This is the dockerfile that I have in the same directory as the .jar file:

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11 as packager
WORKDIR ./whiteboard
COPY col_whiteboard.jar .
EXPOSE 8888
ENV DISPLAY =:0.0
CMD ["java","DrawCanvas"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","col_whiteboard.jar"]
```

This is my build command:

```
$ docker build -t collab_board .
```

And my run command:

```
$ docker run -p 8888 collab_board
```

I am in an Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine when I run the commands.

The  error I get is the following:

```
DrawCanvaException in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '=:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

Please help me understand whats going wrong and how to fix it! I've been stuck on this for days, apologies if it's a stupid question, I'm very new to docker and java GUI applications.

Update:
I have solved the x11 issue by giving all users access to xhost using the command `xhost +`in the terminal, and using the RUN command:

```
docker run --net=host --env="DISPLAY" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" collab_board
```

The container still does not run however, giving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.getInstance(SunFontManager.java:249)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:265)
    at java.desktop/sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1243)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1646)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.getPreferredSize(BasicLabelUI.java:246)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1680)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(FlowLayout.java:609)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1537)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1526)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1731)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1657)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.validateUnconditionally(Container.java:1694)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1050)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
    at collab_whiteboard.DrawCanvas.<init>(DrawCanvas.java:71)
    at collab_whiteboard.DrawCanvas.main(DrawCanvas.java:422)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:379)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:324)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: What do you mean by the Frame gui?

Comment: To correctly set the environment variable, you need to delete either the space `ENV DISPLAY=:0.0` or the equals sign `ENV DISPLAY :0.0`.  There are a bunch of other things you have to set up, though, and many of them aren't in the Dockerfile; I'd recommend installing a JVM on the EC2 instance, `ssh` to it as normal with X forwarding, and run the application without involving Docker.

Comment: @NomadMaker As in the main class extends Frame and has bounds set for it

Comment: @DavidMaze I have now removed the space. What other things do I need to set up in the Dockerfile? I really want to get this working in docker, as I am trying to learn.

Comment: If this is a Swing program, then it should extend JFrame rather than Frame. You need to include the Swing tag, if the problem is in Swing. Does the program run without using Docker?

Comment: @NomadMaker the program runs with no issues without using Docker, I will try extending JFrame instead.

Comment: Sorry, if the program runs, then it's working. No sense in changing this.

Comment: It runs the same using JFrame after a quick test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved the problem by using the updated RUN command and changing the dockerfile to the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN \
apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install default-jre -y
ADD collab_whiteboard.jar whiteboardsys.jar
CMD java -jar whiteboardsys.jar
```